# postgres: Command line SQL: why to connect to database even to execute some SQL commands like to create a new database

Tags: postgresql

I want to execute some SQL commands on the database level in postgresql in linux machine. I want to learn the command line

Eg: i want to run the SQL. I have a role created called `somesuperuser` using phppgadmin.

```
CREATE DATABASE new_database OWNER somesuperuser;
```

I know `postgres` is the default superuser.

I try

```
$ psql -U postgres
psql (11.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE new_database OWNER somesuperuser;
```

Here i can execute the SQL.

But if i try

```
$ psql -U somesuperuser   
psql: FATAL:  database "somesuperuser" does not exist
```

So what i observe is

```
psql -U postgres
```

is equivalent to

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

So whats the need to connect to a database and then only am able to run an SQL command, even to create another database

I feel connecting to a database is OK, if we have to do some operation on that database related. like add tables etc.

Comment: The command `psql` is for connecting to a database, so if you run it it will try to connect to a database. Especially since you’re not giving it any command to run how would it know you don’t want to connect to a specific database but do some generic operations?

Comment: I also found that the article https://blog.dbi-services.com/what-the-hell-are-these-template0-and-template1-databases-in-postgresql/ also explains in detail why its bit confusing initially how postgres works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE DATABASE` is a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html).

Every SQL command is executed by the server process.

For a SQL client to be able to communicate with the server it has to connect to the server.

Due to the Postgres architecture, a connection can only be established **to** a database, because the backend process that handles the client's request is tied to a specific database.

And that's why `psql` (or any other SQL client) requires a connection to *some* database, even if you don't do anything with *that* database.

Comment: so what about `createdb`. Is it also connecting to some database to execute the command Eg: `createdb -O  somesuperuser new_database` so here it creates the `new_database`. So how does it do.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) `createdb` is simply a wrapper around `create database`  and is essentially the same as `psql ... -c 'create database ...` so the same rules apply: to be able to run a SQL command you need a connection which has to be made to a database.

Comment: So basically a `database` can be connected by any `role` based on its `privilages` . Once connected depending on the `role's` `privilages` it can create `databases` or `roles` further. Just connecting to the `database` is the only way to run `SQL commands`. It has no specific meaning as such then why we have to connect to that specific database only. It can be through any database connection but w.r.t the roles privilages. Am i right

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "like an interface", but yes: once you are connected (to a database), you can do whatever the privileges of the connecting role allow you to do

Comment: what happens if i delete all the databases. i will be left with no way eventhought the roles still exist

Comment: Why would you delete all databases? That's like formatting your hard disk. Do you expect your operating system to be prepared for that as well? But can't actually delete all databases, because you can't drop the database that you are connected to and if only a single database is left, you can't drop that (as you need it to connect to the server)

Comment: `But can't actually delete all databases, because you can't drop the database that you are connected to and if only a single database is left, you can't drop that ` - That makes sense.

Comment: I was able to delete all the `databases` using `phppgadmin` when i login as the `superuser`. and `logout` also. Again i could `login` back using the `superuser` and create a `database`. So as per you comment this should not be possible

Comment: Did you also delete `template1` and `template0`?

Comment: It does not show template1 or template0 but this is what is shows after deleting all the databases https://0x0.st/i2xk.png

Comment: Then it probably connects to `template1`

Comment: yes you are right. I tried `psql -U postgres -d template1` it works https://0x0.st/i2x5.png. AND also when i try `psql -d template0` it says `database "template0" is not currently accepting connections`

Answer (score 0):

By default if user do not provide the -d while connecting to psql, it will assume that default database for user is same as user name. e.g for your user `somesuperuser` it will assume that this user has default database named as `somesuperuser`.

If you want to perform any operation without being connected first to psql session and then running a psql command, you may use the following formats, which will give the control back to user after execution of command.

```
./psql -U somesuperuser -d postgres -p 5432 -c "CREATE DATABASE new_database OWNER somesuperuser"
```

The above command will create a database new_database. After this you may create any table/object in the same database by using the below command e.g

```
./psql -U somesuperuser -d new_database -c "create table test (col1 int,col2 int)"
```

or if you have a test.sql file having the multiple ddl and dml for create tables, insert into tables, then you may use the below command

```
./psql -U somesuperuser -d new_database -f /home/root/test.sql
```

Comment: "*If you want to perform any operation without being connected to psql session*" is a bit misleading. You can't do anything on the Postgres server without being connected